# IN / NOT IN and JOIN

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the following tables:

```
students (studentid, firstname, lastname)
finals (studentid, subjectid, finaldate, mark)
subjects (subjectid, subjectname, semester)
```

I need to know the students (bringing up the id) who took a database final exam. I've done the following:

```
select studentid
from finals
where subjectid in (select subjectid
                    from subjects
                    where subjectname = 'database');
```

Do I get the same result if I use a `JOIN` insted of `IN`?

```
select studentid
from finals f, subjects s
where f.subjectid = s.subjectid
and s.subjectname = 'database';
```

And what if I need to know the students (bringing up the id) who have never taken a database final?

Is it the same doing this...

```
select studentid
from finals
where subjectid not in (select subjectid
                        from subjects
                        where subjectname = 'database');
```

...Than this?

```
select studentid
from finals f, subjects s
where f.subjectid = s.subjectid
and s.subjectname <> 'database';
```

Thanks.

Comment: Is it `ever taken a database final` or `never taken a database final`?

Comment: @HarshGupta It's `never taken a database final`. Fixed, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

The answer to your first question is "yes" generally, but you should be using proper join syntax:

```
select studentid
from finals f join
     subjects s
     on f.subjectid = s.subjectid and s.subjectname = 'database';
```

The generally is because duplicates in the `subjects` table would appear in the `join` version but not the `in` version.  The strict equivalent would be:

```
select studentid
from finals f join
     (select distinct subjectid, subjectname
      from subjects s
     ) s
     on f.subjectid = s.subjectid and s.subjectname = 'database';
```

(A `select distinct studentid` comes close but it would eliminate duplicates in the `finals` table if it exists.)

The second answer is "no".  The correct query is a `left outer join` with a `where` filter to only get the rows that do not match:

```
select studentid
from finals f left outer join
     subjects s
     on f.subjectid = s.subjectid and s.subjectname = 'database'
where s.subjectid is not null;
```